# How can I set up the remotes in my original repository as if it was cloned?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have created a Git repository locally and committed a file to it:

```
$ mkdir blarg && cd blarg

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/myuser/tests/blarg/.git/

$ echo a line > test.txt

$ git add .

$ git commit -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) f47ef6d] initial commit
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 100644 test.txt
```

I want my server to host this repository, so I have created a bare empty repository there and configured access to it (this part works fine). I can set this repository as a remote in my local repo and push to it:

```
$ git remote add --track master origin https://git.example.net/repos/blarg.git

$ git remote -v
origin  https://git.example.net/repos/blarg.git (fetch)
origin  https://git.example.net/repos/blarg.git (push)

$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 216 bytes | 216.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://git.example.net/repos/blarg.git
* [new branch]      master -> master

$ git pull
Already up to date.

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git log --oneline
f47ef6d (HEAD -> master, origin/master) initial commit
```

This all seems to work as intended. However, after cloning this repository from the server into a new directory, the `git status` message is slightly different in the cloned repo, and `git log` also shows one more ref than in the original repo:

```
$ cd ..

$ git clone https://git.example.net/repos/blarg.git blarg2
Cloning into 'blarg2'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done

$ cd blarg2

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git log --oneline
f47ef6d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) initial commit
```

Note that git only prints *"Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'."* in the cloned repository, and that the log there mentions `origin/HEAD`.

What's going on, and how can I adjust my original repo to behave like the cloned one?

Comment: This might be useful: https://superuser.com/questions/1192865/git-what-does-an-extra-item-origin-head-mean

Answer (score 1):

> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'

This means that the branch has been setup to track the `master` branch on `origin`. You can set this up on your original local repo like this:

```sh
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/8559522).

> f47ef6d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) initial commit

`origin/HEAD` is pointing to the tip of `master` here because the local repo is using `master` as the default as the branch for `origin` i.e. the branch that will be used by commands like `git log origin` with no branch specified.

You can set this up on you original repo like this:

```sh
git remote set-head origin master
```

See [this](https://superuser.com/a/1192881/1052428), as mentioned by daChihan.